# Card has white bar at bottom

Tags: flutter

I get a white line at the bottom of my Card and I can't figure out how to get rid of it.

[image]

This is my code:

```
return Card(
  margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
  elevation: 8,
  semanticContainer: true,
  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
  child: Stack(
    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
    children: <Widget>[
      Image.asset(
        'assets/push.jpg',
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
      LinearProgressIndicator(
        value: 0.8,
      ),
    ],
  ),
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
  ),
);
```

Any ideas?

Edit: I found out this problem has something to do with the height of the Stack. I have this problem as well with the following code:

```
return Card(
  margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
  elevation: 10,
  semanticContainer: true,
  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        height: 270,
      ),
      LinearProgressIndicator(
        value: 0.8,
      ),
    ]
  ),
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
  ),
);
```

But weirdly not when I change the height of the Container to 200...

Edit 2: With diegoveloper code it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Did you try to play with the elevation value, could it make any changes on this problem ?

Comment: Yes I tried that but that doesn't seem to change anything. However I found that the problem seems to occur with the Image I used. If I change this Image to a Container with height and color, the white bar doesn't appear.

Comment: You can share your fixing way with answering your own question for another's benefit.

Comment: yes but my problem isn't solved... Also forget what I answered before, it seems like this doesn't has anything to do with the Image but with the height of the Stack...

Comment: what's the issue now?

Comment: @diegoveloper the issue is still the same. I have a white bar under my card. Meanwhile I found out, that this occurs when the height is around 300...

Comment: check my answer below

Comment: Your code seem's working like we expected for me.. So have you checked your card theme to see if you have apply a bottom border for it?

Answer (score 2):

Try using elevation less or equals than 5

```
        Container(
                  height: 300.0,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  child: Card(
                    elevation: 5,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
                    child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        height: 270,
                      ),
                        LinearProgressIndicator(
                          value: 0.8,
                        ),
                    ]),
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                  )),
```

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the help but that didn't solve the problem. The white bar is still there with your solution and also I still wanna use my Image (The first code I posted, the 2nd was just an example). I don't have a fixed height of my Card.

Comment: could you update the image of how it looks like with my code? also update your code

Comment: I added the picture but what do you mean with update my code? I use the exact same code you did. But as I said, in the end my Card won't have a fixed height, so this solution won't work anyways.

Comment: did you add the Expanded to the LinearProgressIndicator , and changed the elevation to 4 ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186320/discussion-between-diegoveloper-and-jonas).